# Multiply two values in a form

Tags: javascript, html

For my code, I am trying to call 2 parameters into a function. Once you have left the 2nd input box, and multiply the 2 numbers passed through and put it in the third text box.  if either of the first 2 input boxes are empty, then color them light red.  This is my code so far, what am I missing?

Javascript:

```
function multiply(one, two) {
if(one==""){
this.style.color='red';
}
if(two==""){
this.style.color='red';
}
else{
txt1=one * two;
return txt1;
}

}
```

HTML5:

```
First Value: <input type="text" name="mFirst" />
Second Value: <input type="text" name="mLast" onblur="multiply(mFirst.value, mLast.value)" />
Multiplication of First and Second Value: <input type="text" name="answer">
```

Comment: first of all you cant just return the value, you need to assign it to the answer box

Comment: I was wondering about that...where do we assign the returned value to the answer box?

Comment: phrogz got it for you below -- (this.form.elements.answer.value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```html
<input … onblur="multiply.call(this,this.form.elements.mFirst.value,this.form.elements.mLast.value)" >
```

```js
function multiply(one, two) {
  if(one && two){
    this.form.elements.answer.value = one * two;
  } else {
    this.style.color='red';
  }
}
```

*Empty strings are non-truthy values, thus `one && two` will only be true if neither value is an empty string.*

*Using `call` allows you to set the value of `this` used inside the function.*

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b5Ltt/

You might want to look at the [HTML5 `<output>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output).

Comment: Try testing this with the value 0

Comment: @JohnnyHarlamert Try it yourself; there's a demo link. Hint: The number `0` is falsy, but the string `"0"` is truthy.

Comment: I typed the word "foo" and got NaN. Also the form.elements reference is outdated and couldnt be further from HTML5 standards. I also dont get why you are using call. You also have bloated the DOM with such a long function reference. This is crazy! The worst checked answer I ever seen

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing `this` to your `multiply()` function.

If you want to change `this.style` you can pass `this` as an argument.

Also, you should change `mFirst.value` to `this.form.elements.mFirst.value` and the same for `mLast.value`

HTML:

```
First Value: <input type="text" name="mFirst" />
Second Value: <input type="text" name="mLast" onblur="multiply( this , mFirst.value, mLast.value)" />
Multiplication of First and Second Value: <input type="text" name="answer">
```

JavaScript:

```
function multiply( _this, one, two) {
    var txt1 = 0;
    if(one=="" || two==""){
        // Should set both colors to red
        _this.form.elements.mFirst.style.color = 'red';
        _this.form.elements.mLast.style.color= 'red';
    }else{

        // parse float in the case of a decimal and set de
        one = parseFloat(one);
        two= parseFloat(two);

        txt1 = one * two;
        _this.form.elements.answer.value = txt1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's starting to work, but a question.  How do I get "txt1" to appear in the third input box ("answer")?

Comment: -1 The logic here is incorrect (as it is in the OP's) when `one` is empty. Further, this just sets a global variable.

Comment: @Phrogz I just need the first and 2nd box to multiply after leaving focus on the 2nd box and the answer to show up in the third box.

Answer (score 0):

```
First Value: <input type="text" name="mFirst" id="mFirst" />
Second Value: <input type="text" name="mLast" id="mLast" onblur="multiply()" />
Multiplication of First and Second Value: <input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" />

function multiply()
{
    var num_one = document.getElementById('mFirst').value;
    var num_two = document.getElementById('mLast').value;

    if(typeof num_one === 'number' && typeof num_two === 'number')
    {
        document.getElementById('answer').value = (parseInt(num_one) * parseInt(num_two));
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('answer').style.color = 'red'; // not recommended method
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a similar note, why this doesn't work?

```
function monetaryfields()
{
if (multiply) { total.value = unitary.value * quantity.value; }
else { unitary.value = total.value / quantity.value; }
}

<form>
<ul>
<li>Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity" onblur="monetaryfields.call(true)" /></li>
<li>Unitary: <input type="text" name="unitary" onblur="monetaryfields.call(true)" /></li>
<li>Total: <input type="text" name="total" onblur="monetaryfields.call(false)" /></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Comment: nevermind...

this works:

    function calc(multiply)
    {
        if (multiply) { tt.value = parseFloat(qt.value * un.value).toFixed(2); }
        else { un.value = parseFloat(tt.value / qt.value).toFixed(2); }
    }

    <form>
        <ul>
            <li>Qt: <input type="text" id="qt" onblur="calc(true)" /></li>
            <li>Unt: <input type="text" id="un" onblur="calc(true)" /></li>
            <li>Tot: <input type="text" id="tt" onblur="calc(false)" /></li>
        </ul>
    </form>